# Magmi changing SKU for no apparent reason

Tags: php, magento, import, magmi

Im making a import for a client using Magmi. and the weirdest thing is happening.

Imagine a list of products by SKU

sku1

sku2

sku3

when the import is finished it looks like this

sku1

sku1

sku3

i have no idea why this is happening and why Magmi is changing the SKU of a product

**In real life**  [sku::301e-1204] is changed to [sku::601E-4123]

**First stage is to read product.xml and below is the result of one product**

```
[sku] => 301e-1204
[price] => 39.9500
[ecommerce_guid] => 29C6C1E8-06FC-4C52-A652-002D1DBA8A78
[product_variation_id] => 147146-7970
```

**Second stage is to read stock.xml and below is the result of one product**

```
[sku] => 301e-1204
[qty] => 1
[use_config_manage_stock] => 1
[is_in_stock] => 1
```

**this is the function that injects it into magento database**

```
public function importProduct($product)
{
    $this->magmi->ingest($product);

    print_r($product);
}
```

**the array results you see are produced by the print_r($product); line**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem comes from sku value interpretation. It has been fixed in latest git however.

in comparison operators, your 2 skus would match equality !!!

See this snippet:

```
<?php
$x="301e-1204";
$y="601e-4312";
echo "$x/$y=>".($x==$y?"Y":"N");
?>
```

It would echo "Y" at the end. In fact, PHP takes those as "numbers" (since XeY is a valid numerical notation) if using "relax" comparison operator "==". This doesn't happend with strict comparison `(===)` nor strcmp.

this sku comparison code has been fixed for a while now in latest Git
see this [Git Commit](https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/commit/2335356b313df8be1a4332dd1ebaee8eb5476722).

Try latest git version, it has many bugfixes & enhancements. It should fix your problem.

Comment: im already using the latest version 0.7.18 - so i need to change the magmi engine to an absolute comparison?

Comment: 0.7.18 is latest "official" release, but a bit old compared to Git. but yes, you may change the magmi engine with the same code than the git commit (strcmp).